# How to avoid user turn off the screen which result in the wifi turned off during downloading

Tags: android

In my application, I use `AsyncTask` to download large files (300M+). I noticed that when the user turns off their screen (locks their device), the wifi will disconnect and the download will hang.

I wonder if it is possible to avoid this?

Comment: Do not keep screen on. Firt take a look on DownloadManager class ... if you still wana use asynctask search for wake locks(PowerManager class)

Comment: DownloadManager is only supported at api level with 9+. I can not use it.

Comment: There is also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You required to implement WakeLock in your application. Wakelock will wake up the CPU incase of screen is off and performs the operations in normal ways.

Write down following code before starting the AsyncTask,

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK|PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "bbbb");
wl.acquire();
```

You need to write `wl.release();` on PostExecution() method. And you need to define permission in AndroidManifest.xml as follows,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: And don't forget to release it when your done by doing wl.release(). I encourage you to read this (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html ) because wwakelock can hardly affect battery consumption.

Comment: @tanou, please read the full answer, I already mentioned that part. :)

Comment: my bad, page wasn't refreshed ;)

Comment: Wonderful, this solve my problem? Can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

The common practice in this case is to take a [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) to keep the CPU awake, and take a [WifiLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html) to keep the wifi connected, so that your app keeps running even if the screen is turned off.

Don't forget to release the locks when you're done!